# NoSuchElementException Error in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

My main goal is extract information from a website that contains name,address,socket-type,station-model parameters from map of website.I decided to extract it with Selenium with python. At first i extracted xpaths of all html elements that i intended to extract information from and i used `driver.find_elements` method but after i run code, i get **NoSuchElementException** error.

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Name="/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/span"
Address="/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]"
  StationModel="/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/d  iv/div/div[2]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]"
  SocketType=""

  path_chrome = r'C:\Users\efede\OneDrive\Masaüstü\F\exeler\chromedriver.exe'
  path_firefox=r'C:\Users\efede\OneDrive\Masaüstü\F\exeler\geckodriver.exe'

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_chrome)

  NameList=list()
  AddressList=list()
  StationModelList=list()

  driver.get('https://esarj.com/harita?s=TR-BOL-001')

  names=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,Name)
  adresses=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,Address)
  models=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,StationModel)

  driver.close()

  print(names)


    zip_df=pd.DataFrame([NameList,AddressList,StationModelList],columns["İstasyonAdı","Adres","İstasyonModeli"])
  zip_df.to_excel("ESARJ.xlsx",sheet_name="ESARJ(12.6.23)")
```

and i got this error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49202/devtools/browser/5844b146-cafa-45a9-bdfb-bc07e721d63d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\efede\OneDrive\Masaüstü\F\Scrapping\esarj.py", line 27, in <module>
    adresses=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,Address)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\efede\OneDrive\Masaüstü\F\Scrapping\scrappingenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 831, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\efede\OneDrive\Masaüstü\F\Scrapping\scrappingenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute   
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\efede\OneDrive\Masaüstü\F\Scrapping\scrappingenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.110)
```

Comment: Efe, just a note it's bad practice to build Xpath locator's the way you have, I understand you might just be copying them from Chrome but this is not how you should be using XPath and they might very well lead to flaky tests in future. Rather try narrow it down with a locator as close as possible to your element, example `//table [@id='example']/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/span`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the limited understanding of your question, I have written down a working code below. Please refer below.

**Note** that I have refactored your code by removing `absolute XPaths` and replacing them with `relative XPaths` and also by applying `waits`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

Name = "//td[text()='Şarj Noktası:']//following::span[1]"
Address = "//td[text()='Adres:']//following::td[1]"
StationModel = "//td[text()='İstasyon Modeli:']//following::td[1]"
SocketType = ""

path_chrome = r'C:\Users\efede\OneDrive\Masaüstü\F\exeler\chromedriver.exe'
path_firefox=r'C:\Users\efede\OneDrive\Masaüstü\F\exeler\geckodriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_chrome)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get('https://esarj.com/harita?s=TR-BOL-001')

# Accept cookie
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Tamam')]"))).click()

names = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Name))).text

# click on Lokasyon tab
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Lokasyon']"))).click()
adresses = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Address))).text

# click on Teknik tab
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Teknik']"))).click()
models = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, StationModel))).text

print(names)
print(adresses)
print(models)

driver.close()
```

**Console Result:**

```
Highway Outlet Alışveriş ve Yaşam Merkezi
Ankara-İstanbul Otoyolu, 227. Km, Elmalık Mevkii, 14030 Bolu / Türkiye
PM 22kVA

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your influence. Your code works in my python env too but i aim to collect these data from each every station on that map and create lists with that data and finally create a dataframe with these lists. Do you have any idea to make it happen?

Comment: You are asking more than one question in a single post. You should split and ask one question at a time. If `NoSuchElementException` issue has fixed, I suggest ask a new question with specific query and specific code trials where you are facing issue. If you think this answer helped resolve your original issue(which is `NoSuchElementException`), you can accept this answer so that it is not left un-answered.